# Can the CW prompt be disabled after it has been shown a number of times?

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki

I often use the Community Wiki feature to move solutions that have incorrectly been edited into a question as an addendum. Almost always this is done by new members who doesn't know we don't use [solved] devices.

To repair this situation I open the question editor, copy the answer section to clipboard, paste it in an answer box, click the CW flag, click OK to the alert message, add a prefix note to say I am posting on behalf of the OP, submit, then roll back the question to the last non-answer state.

The alert message says this:

> Are you sure you want to make this post Community Wiki?
>
> Doing so will remove explicit ownership and you will no longer earn reputation for upvotes on it. Once saved, this option cannot be unchecked without moderator assistance.

This is all a bit of a faff, and it would save a step if the CW alert did not pop up - I've seen it a few hundred times now! Could it be suppressed in any one of the following cases?

- For users over reputation level X (e.g. 5K)
- For users who have posted at least Y wiki answers (e.g. 20)
- For users who tick an option in their profile settings

Comment: Or there could be an option in the pop-up for "Don't show me this message any more"

Comment: @TinyGiant: yes, that would do it. It's presently just a JS alert box, but it could be changed into a modal of some kind.

Comment: Technically it's a confirm box, but yeah.

Comment: Is this *really* such a huge issue?

Comment: For the first case (users above 5K), I would disagree, as I've never used that feature before and would appreciate the warning. The profile settings seems best here.

Comment: @Cœur: I don't mind which way it goes. I suggested other options as UI designers dislike proliferating profile options these days, preferring a sensible default behaviour instead.

Comment: Btw, when I see solutions posted as a part of the question, I just comment and ask the OP to post it as answer (and delete it from his question), with a link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Bergi: I do see people taking that option, good point. One could roll back and not re-post as CW, but in my estimation most low-rep users won't bother themselves with posting it correctly, believing it was perfectly OK as it was. So if it is clear which part is the answer (and it is not always) I will sometimes do it for them.

Comment: @halfer I found that most people who bother to come back and share their solution will also bother to do it correctly, one just has to tell them when they don't know what is OK. It's nothing to do with reputation, they just aren't familiar with the site yet.

Comment: @Bergi: I don't mean to disparage community members for a low score, far from it. However my experience has been somewhat different - people are rarely motivated to fix their answering style. They will always do it "next time".

Comment: Could be done with a one-liner: `$(".js-post-editor input[type=checkbox][name=communitymode]").off("click").one("click");` but I'm too lazy to figure out how to make it run only after `StackExchange.editor.init()` has been called.

Comment: @Siguza: is that for TamperMonkey? I used to run that, but suspected it of adding poor performance to my FF browser, so disabled it.

Comment: @halfer It's just JavaScript, nothing browser- or plugin-dependent... and while it is based on jQuery, which is usually to blame for poor performance, the entire SE network uses jQuery, so the performance _shouldn't be any worse_ than without it. Provided, of course, you let it run on SE sites only, otherwise it's gonna listen for events on inexistent elements on every site...