# I don't earn reputation on Meta anyway...why should I be warned of it when I'm making a post Community Wiki?

Tags: bug, meta, community-wiki

This seems...wrong to me:

[image]

I don't earn reputation on Meta anyway.  At least, not in a visible sense.  Reputation exists for badges like Epic, but it isn't *as* significant here as the main site.

From that perspective, this copy reads confusingly.  Could it be rephrased to something that applies clearer to Meta?

Note that this pertains to Meta.  The main site's warning would likely be fine since the context is clear.

Comment: Because, reputation isn't the only difference between CW'ed post and non-CW'ed ones. You also allow anyone with 100 reputation to edit the post without review. The real bug here is that the message only touch upon the topic of reputation and just glances at the ownership one.

Comment: @Braiam you seem to be assuming the request is to remove it. It is to reword it to make it relevant to meta. I.e. To remove the bit about reputation.

Comment: @MartinSmith Since it would be estrange that SE would modify the text for meta (cue voting tooltip text), my bug actually is more likely to be fixed, since it would solve main *and* meta messages.

Comment: Why would it be strange to have customised messages for sites with different behaviour? I presume all these strings are already easily localisable for the foreign language sites.

Comment: Even though you don't earn visible reputation on meta this will have an effect on your progress for reputation driven badges such as mortarboard and legendary so arguably the warning is still valid.

Comment: @MartinSmith Maybe more importantly is tag score. If it doesn't contribute toward badges, then it won't contribute to getting access to the dupe hammer. In certain cases where it's a highly upvoted answer and you're close to the edge of the gold badge, could it result in the *loss* of it?

Comment: Related: the CW warning [on the main site is shown too often](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345050/can-the-cw-prompt-be-disabled-after-it-has-been-shown-a-number-of-times) as well.

Comment: @MartinSmith:  I acknowledge that rep is still a thing on Meta, but it's not *as* important here as it would be on the main site.  I'm merely asking for the copy to be less confusing for Meta as opposed to the main site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically I suppose it's because Meta and QA use the same software to run themselves, so anything that hasn't been manually tweaked is probably similar.

In actuality though, that message does contain a part relevant to meta:

> Doing so will remove explicit ownership [...]

This is important because anyone with 100 rep will be able to edit it and people are also more tolerant with content heavy edits on CW posts then on posts of other people.

I agree though the message could use a tweaking, maybe to something like this:

> Doing so will remove explicit ownership from you. Once saved, this option cannot be reversed without moderator assistance.

Comment: The removal of ownership is important not only for the technical effects of how people are *allowed* to interact with it, but semantically for conveying information.  A reader of a CW post knows that it is a collaboration of many people, rather than the work of one person, and they know that if they see a CW post they can collaborate in changing it's semantic meaning themselves, whereas for a non-CW post that's not appropriate.  The rep change (and the rep requirement for editing) are both just side effects of that.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, which is why I suggested to keep the warning but trim it.

Comment: I was just expanding further on your points, not disagreeing with any of them.